# How to inject service for SignalR hub

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

In my ASP.NET Core 7 MVC application, in `startup.cs` hub service is injected like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddScoped<IHubContext<OstupultHub>>();
}
```

Running the application throws an exception

> System.ArgumentException   HResult=0x80070057
> Cannot instantiate implementation type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.IHubContext`1[Store.Hubs.OstupultHub]' for service type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.IHubContext`1[Store.Hubs.OstupultHub]'
>
> Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
> StackTrace:
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.Populate() in /_/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/src/ServiceLookup/CallSiteFactory.cs:line 68 ...

How to fix this so that hub can be used in MVC controller constructor like

```
public MyController(IHubContext<OstupultHub> hubContext ) { ...
```

Hub class is defined as

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
namespace Store.Hubs;

public class OstupultHub : Hub
{  ... 
}
```

According to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-7.0

it should work.

Currently I'm using in controller constructor
IServiceProvider

```
public OstupultController(IServiceProvider _provider )
  {
    provider = _provider;
  }
```

and then in controller

```
  public async Task<ContentResult> ReceiveLogFile()
  {
    var pultHub = provider.GetRequiredService<IHubContext<OstupultHub>>();
    await pultHub.Clients.All.SendAsync("sendLogFileMessage");
    return new ContentResult() { Content ="sent" };
  }
```

Looking for use service directly like other servies.

Comment: `Controller needs send message to clients`, then I think what you required maybe, you want to have an API which should send messages to some/all clients when the API is called. Then the link you mentioned is correct and it should work. I tested in my side before and it worked for me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> service is injected as `services.AddScoped<IHubContext<OstupultHub>>();`

AFAIK you don't need to register hubs this way. Just call `services.AddSignalR()` in the `ConfigureServices` and `MapHub<OstupultHub>(...);` in the `Configure`.

Comment: How to call this hub service from controller?  Using `IHubContext<OstupultHub> hubContext` in constructor throws cannot instantiate implemention type exception  as described in question.

Comment: Why are you trying to call it from another controller?

Comment: Controller needs send message to clients. I updated question and added workaround which I'm using currently.

Comment: @Andrus  follow up to the original question - have you removed the original registration (the quoted one)? As for the workaround - it does not make much sense, if it works, constructor injection should work also.

Comment: Yes, I removed it. `provider.GetRequiredService<IHubContext<OstupultHub>>()` is used in controller method to get hub service. How to remove it so that service reference can passed as argument in controller constructor like other services?

Comment: @Andrus just add `IHubContext<OstupultHub>` as a constructor parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In Program.cs, like what Guru said using `services.AddSignalR();` and

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Privacy}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");
            });
```

In my controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly IHubContext<ChatHub> _hubContext;


        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IHubContext<ChatHub> hubContext)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _hubContext = hubContext;
        }

        public IActionResult IndexAsync()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public async Task getInfo() {
            await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("Notify", $"Home page loaded at: {DateTime.Now}");
        }
```