# How to make SignalR catch a custom event of an ASP.NET Core MVC Web App

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm trying to catch an event coming from a background asynchronous task and I'm struggling to do it. The code that I've tried to accomplish that is this one.

JavaScript portion:

```
document.addEventListener("MessageEvent", function (event, param1, param2) {
    //console.log(param1);
    //console.log(param2);
    connection.invoke("SendMessage", param1, param2).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

C# event Launch:

```
string s = "whatever";
EventHandler<messageEventArgs> handler = MessageEvent;
messageEventArgs eventArgs = new messageEventArgs();
eventArgs.text = s;
eventArgs.id = 1;
handler?.Invoke(null, eventArgs);
```

C# event declaration:
`public static event EventHandler<messageEventArgs> MessageEvent;`

I've confirmed that the event is launched and that the .js file is unable to catch that event... I don't know anything else.

I'll appreciate some solution...

PD: Another option could be to directly call the SignalR Hub function (`SendMessage()`) that I'm calling when catching the event. In case somebody knows how to do it that way.

---

### Edit

Let me upload the complete code for clarification.

`ChatHub : Hub` code

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace HTTPChat_Application.Hubs;

public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public static int i = 0;
    public async Task SendMessageToAll(string user, string message) {
        //if(i==0){Program.chatHub = this;i++;} 
    Console.WriteLine(Program.ExternClass.ReceivingQueue.First() 
    .ToString());
    await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, 
    Program.ExternClass.ReceivingQueue.First().ToString());
    }
}
```

`chat.js` Code:

```
"use strict";

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();

//Disable the send button until connection is established.
document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = true;

connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
    // We can assign user-supplied strings to an element's textContent because it
    // is not interpreted as markup. If you're assigning in any other way, you 
    // should be aware of possible script injection concerns.
    li.textContent = `${user} says ${message}`;
});

connection.start().then(function () {
    document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = false;
}).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});

document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var user = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;
    connection.invoke("SendMessageToAll", user, message).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});

document.addEventListener("MessageEvent", function (event, param1, param2) {
    connection.invoke("SendMessageToAll", param1, param2).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: is it possible for you to using dependency injection to  inject hub into you event and call your js method directly?

Comment: I mean [this feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-7.0#inject-an-instance-of-ihubcontext-in-a-controller), because I don't know how you write your event, pls check if this is ok for you.

Comment: pls correct me if I misunderstood your requirement, but for asp.net core signalr, what we ususally do is like the link I shared

Comment: Yes, I think you understood it correctly, but your solution did not work for me. My `hubContext.Clients` is empty, so the `SendMessage` Hub method is not called. How could I achieve it?

Comment: Hi, could you pls share your codes about the event? Because I don't know about the event, what I know is, when we want to call signalr events out of the hub, we need to inject the hubcontext. I have a [test here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74976775/how-to-inject-service-for-signalr-hub/74979728#74979728). If `hubContext.Clients` is null, I'm afraid it's related with the event itself....

Comment: Thanks, but this is what I already did. Maybe your .js or :Hub files are different than mines, I'll add them to the original question.

Comment: `document.addEventListener("MessageEvent"` could only monitor event in the browser, but could't cover events sent by asp.net core event... Could u pls share the demo for your asp.net core event?

Comment: Here it is:
https://github.com/Rogeraj2001/SignalRMvcChat.git